# Whay my wifi is get disconnecte frequently in ubountu 17.10?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wifi, ubuntu-17.04

I have upgraded ubuntu to v 17.10 in my laptop and I face to this problem what my wifi sometimes can't connect to Internet and again recconnet.
Does anyone face to this problem and solve it?

Comment: this question belogs to askubuntu.com

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I saw many of them that there wifi driver is not working and performed many commands showed in google but that also dosen't work..

So with all this problems what i concluded is that during installation may be some packages are not being installed (due to any reasons) and over installing will also not help (in some conditions)

Lastly, format & install ubuntu again in your system & you may find it working.

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question, and the question itself isn't a great fit for StackOverflow. For something so broad, try to leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

There is a open BUG on launchpad from Geoff Williams Regarding WIFI.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1725609

His workaround:

- sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
- sudo dpkg-reconfigure bcmwl-kernel-source

worked for me like a charm.